# Ubuntu Server 18.04 cannot switch to external display

Tags: server, 18.04, display, hdmi

I have an old Toshiba laptop from 2008 on which I have installed ubuntu server 18.04.  The built in laptop screen is cracked, so I had it connected to a VGA monitor for a while and it worked fine.  I wanted to connect it to my TV, so I bought a VGA to HDMI display converter, but when I use that converter, the TV doesn't receive any input. VGA to HDMI shouldn't require any additional drivers, so does anyone know what could be going on?

xrandr output:

```
Can't open display
```

lshw -c video output:

```
*-display:0               
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 2
   bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
   version: 07
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
   resources: irq:16 memory:f4000000-f43fffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff ioport:1800(size=8) memory:c0000-dffff


*-display:1 UNCLAIMED
       description: Display controller
       product: Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2.1
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.1
       version: 07
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:f4400000-f44fffff
```

I'm pretty new to CLI on Ubuntu, so just let me know if there is other relevant information I should post

Comment: Sounds like the adapter is faulty. Did you try it on a different device? Are you sure it is a VGA->HDMI converter and not HDMI->VGA?

Comment: That's a good thought - it should be VGA->HDMI, but I'll double check.  I've tried it on another device and it didn't work there either, so it's either faulty or HDMI->VGA.

Answer (score 1):

Seems as if the adapter was an HDMI to VGA cable, not VGA to HDMI...